# Saving and displaying "nested" JSON data from API

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, api

I have the following format of JSON data fetched from an API and stored in IntentList

```
{
        "id": 22,
        "name": "IntentName",
        "fk_app": 3,
        "fk_intent": null,
        "nlu_models": [],
        "sentences": [
            {
                "text": "text1",
                "id": 2308              
            },
            {
                "text": "text2",
                "id": 2309
            },......
```

So there are these levels : the first having "name" and "sentences", and the second which is inside sentences, having "text".
My goal is to be able to search the API data **By text** and to display on each row the name and text found inside the sentences related to that text.
Therefore if I search "text" this would appear => `IntentName text1 IntentName text2`
if I search text1 this would appear => `IntentName text1`

-----What I have done/tried so far-----
I searched for corresponding text and stored its intent object and was only able to display its intent name
Typescript:

```
 fetchIntentsTxt(event: any) {
    if (event.target.value === '') {
      return this.searchResultINTxt = [];
    }
this.searchResultINTxt = this.IntentList.filter(
      i => i.sentences.some(
        s => s.text.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())));
}
```

Html:

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="searchInputINTxt" (keyup)="fetchIntentsTxt($event)"
                    class="form-control" id="search0" placeholder="Search for Intents by Text">

  <a #myIntentTxt *ngFor="let intentTxt of searchResultINTxt" >{{intentTxt.sentences.text(this doesn't work obviously)}}<span
                          class="float-right">{{intentTxt.name}}</span> <br></a>
```

Any recommendation is appreciated, even if it meant changing the search function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As sentences has more than one object/text what do you want to do if the search string matches more than one text?

Comment: I already displayed an example, it would display them aswell along with their Intent name, regardless if it's the same intent of not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pyaq7a

I would just create a new array in the fetchIntentsTxt method and add the data I want to display by the user input/search. After "filtering" all the data I need I set it to the variable thats iterated over in the View/Template.

```
public fetchIntentsTxt(searchValue: string): void {
    const searchResults = [];
    for (const entry of this.intentList) {
      for (const sentence of entry.sentences) {
        if (sentence.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
          searchResults.push({
            name: entry.name,
            text: sentence.text,
          });
        }
      }
    }

    this.searchResultINTxt = searchResults;
}
```

View:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="searchInputINTxt" (ngModelChange)="fetchIntentsTxt($event)" class="form-control" id="search0" name="search0" placeholder="Search for Intents by Text"/><br />

<a #myIntentTxt *ngFor="let intentTxt of searchResultINTxt">
    {{ intentTxt.text }}<span class="float-right">{{ intentTxt.name }}</span>
    <br/>
</a>
```

Also note here, I used the (ngModelChange) instead of the (keyup) on the search input so I do not need to hassle around with the events and just get the value I need for filtering.

Comment: Thank you, everything you recommended worked out perfectly. I appreciate your help and time.